# Swift: How can I vertically centre a view/label depending on the device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to vertically centre a label when the keyboard is visible across all devices (iPhone 5 - 7 Plus).

Currently, the label only vertically centres on the iPhone 5 screen, but that's only because I've set it manually using the code below:

```
    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {

    let userInfo:NSDictionary = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.emptyStateMessageTopConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - 145
        self.updateViewConstraints()
        self.emptyDataInfoView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

My guess would be to find the size of the UIView when the keyboard is visible and based on the device, adjust the auto layout constraints.

I don't know whether this is right, but I'm seriously struggling to find out the method.

Using the above function does the following:

**iPhone 5/SE:**

The below image, you can see the description is centred.
[image]

**iPhone 7 Plus:**

The below image, you can see that the description isn't centred.
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line to

```
self.emptyStateMessageTopConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight - 145
```

this

```
self.emptyStateMessageTopConstraint.constant = (self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardHeight)/2 - yourlabelheight/2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can you explain how you worked this out?? @Prakash

Comment: your screen height - keyboard height / 2 will give you the mid point of screen area above keyboard then substracting half height of your label will give you the exact y position from where you have to place your label.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Add your label's constraint (center y) to the center of your view, on Keyboard will appear change your bottom constraint of your view += keyboard height. the label in the center of the view will relayout after decreasing the view size on keyboard show to stay in the center. note that view does not have height constraint, just top and bottom constraint .

**OR** if you don't have any view in background to change the bottom constraint, you can change the centerConstraint of your label += keyboardHeight.  to go a little higher on keyboard show.